# Найти подстроку в строке и вставить туда значение

Tags: строки, swift

Есть строка, у него есть подстрока `table` в строке их может быть N-ое количество.
так же есть массив значений назовем его `setValues`, `setValues.count` будет равен количеству `table` в строке.

Задача состоит отследить все эти `table` и вставить после него значение из массива по индексу. К примеру если это первая подстрока `table` то после него вставляем `setValues[0]` и тд.

Проект на [гитхаб](https://github.com/muaviya/parseString.git)

Вот что я сделал:

```
var string = "table table table"
let substring = "table"
let setValues = ["_o_", "_fo_", "_sen_"]
// Результат должен быть следующий:
// "table _o_ table _fo_ table _sen_"

var index = 0
var stepIndex = 0

var i = 0

var stringLoc = string
for char in string {
    if substring.first == char {
        let startOfFoundCharacter = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        let lengthOfFoundCharacter = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: (substring.count + index))
        let range = startOfFoundCharacter..<lengthOfFoundCharacter
        
        // если в строке нашли подстроку "table"
        if string.substring(with: range) == substring {
            stepIndex = index + substring.count
                        
            let trueIndex = stringLoc.index(stringLoc.startIndex, offsetBy: stepIndex)
            stringLoc.insert(contentsOf: setValues[i], at: trueIndex)
        
            i += 1
        }
    }
    index += 1
}
```

"Пробегаюсь" по всей строке ищу наш `table` достаю индекс вставляю нужное нам значение.

Но, надо учитывать, что, при каждой итерации наша строка меняется и `stepIndex` надо двигать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот например так можно это реализовать, мы тут используем `NSString` для простоты операций с подстроками, тут мы используем `range` для ограничения области поиска после каждой замены

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let string = "table table table"
    let substring = "table"
    let setValues = ["_o_", "_fo_", "_sen_"]
    
    var nsString: NSMutableString!
    var range: NSRange!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        nsString = NSMutableString(string: string)
        range = NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)
        
        for i in 0..<setValues.count {
            insertSubstring(" \(setValues[i])", after: substring)
        }

        print(nsString)
    }

    func insertSubstring(_ valueString: String, after searchString: String) {
        let nsRange = nsString.range(of: searchString, options: [], range: range)
        nsString.insert(valueString, at: nsRange.upperBound)
        let offset = nsRange.location + valueString.count
        range = NSMakeRange(offset, nsString.length - offset)
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Выручили. Безмерно благодарен.

Comment: @KerimKhasbulatov на здоровье